# Nhibernate and Multithreading

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, nhibernate

i have a multi-threading applications it has something like this:

Thread1:

```
    while(true)
    {
         //read data 

         //change and update
           thread.sleep(500);
    }
```

Thread2:

```
    //UpdateDate from time to time based on an event from somewhere else....
```

the application crash only in release time and it point out that a method in nhibernate "aftercommit" or something crashes i assume it something has to do with threading and nhibernate i can think of a solution for this by disableing cache or something in nhibernate.

has any one faced something similar ? any idea how to completely disable caching ?

Environment:

Windows7.
.net4
Nhibernate 2.1
Windows Forms
nhibernate dataaccess generated by codesmith nhibernate template.

Comment: 1. What is the exception?
2. Where do you create and dispose sessions (a session is not thread safe)?
3. Do you use stateless sessions or normal ones?

Answer (score 5):

The only artifact that is thread safe in nhibernate is the session factory. Make sure that you are not using the same session between different threads.